# What is the sum of the quadratic residues of prime $p=4k + 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If prime $p=4k + 1$ we know that if a is a quadratic residue then $-a$ is a quadratic residue, So there are $(p - 1)/4$ pairs of integers whose sum is $p$.  So the sum over all quadratic residues is $p(p-1)/4 = (4k + 1)k$.
Summing the quadratic residues over a prime $p=4k + 3$ seems to be much more difficult. The sums are given in Sloane's OEIS A076409.  Is it possible to give a simple proof of the sums (for $p = 4k +3$) being congruent to $0 (\text{mod }p)$?  Here I am assuming they are congruent to $0 (\text{mod }p)$ based on emperical evidence.

Comment: You want to assume $p > 3$, since otherwise the sum is not congruent to $0$ mod $p$. Let $u$ be the sum of all quadratic residues. Let $r$ be some quadratic nonresidue $\not\equiv -1 \mod p$ (this exists since $p > 3$). Then, $\left(1+r\right) u$ is congruent to $1+2+\cdots+\left(p-1\right)$ modulo $p$, because any nontrivial residue modulo $p$ is either a quadratic residue or a quadratic nonresidue, in which case it is (congruent to) $r$ times a quadratic residue. Thus, $\left(1+r\right) u \equiv 1+2+\cdots+\left(p-1\right) = p\left(p-1\right)/2 \equiv 0 \mod p$, whence $u \equiv 0 \mod p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More direct, but less elegant than darij's proof:

We have $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^2 = \frac{p(p-1)(2p-1)}{6}$.  This sum has each quadratic residue repeated twice, so, assuming $p\neq 2$, the sum of the quadratic residues is $\frac{p(p-1)(2p-1)}{6} \cdot 2^{-1} \pmod{p}$.  If $p\neq 3$, this is clearly $0\pmod{p}$.

Comment: I originally marked this answer with an up vote and a green check mark.  However, upon further consideration I do not believe that the argument is correct. You can't just divide the sum of squares by 2.  This not even an integer for primes congruent to 3 mod 4.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer I've updated it to be a little more clear.  You are correct that you can't divide by $2$ in the integers, but my intention was to divide modulo $p$, which is completely fine for $p\neq 2$.

Comment: OK, I understand now.  Thanks.